# Error when trying to use webhook with Google Forms

Tags: javascript, webhooks

I am using `Google Forms`, and when I send the answer, I want for the answer to be sent via webhook. Here is my current code:

```js
var POST_URL = "my webhook url";
function onSubmit(e) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var allResponses = form.getResponses();
    var latestResponse = allResponses[allResponses.length - 1];
    var response = latestResponse.getItemResponses();
    var payload = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var question = response[i].getItem().getTitle();
        var answer = response[i].getResponse();
        payload[question] = answer;
    }
  
    var options = {
        "method": "post",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
};
```

It gives me this error as soon as I run it:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://WEBHOOK WEBSTIE returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

I `.log`ged `options`, and it was not empty.
I have little no experience with JS, as I want to use it for webhook only.

Comment: Does `payload` have properties in it?

Comment: @NickParsons What do you mean "properties"?

Comment: As in keys. Objects have properties/keys, eg: the object `{foo: 1}` has the property/key of `foo` (that has a value of `1`). Your `for` loop adds keys/properties to your `payload` object. So another way of asking what I'm trying to see is, if you add a log within your for loop, do you see it executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of more research, I have found that the issue turned out to be in the `"payload"` parameter.

```js
var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify({"content": JSON.stringify({payload}))
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
```